# Express MVC with sub-apps and shared templates/views

Tags: node.js, express

Node MVC

Ok so I’m currently building a Node/Express MVC boilerplate for all future projects. The requirements dictate that sub apps must be supported to help organise code, and to create a separation of concerns amongst different areas of the site e.g. user account section and the non-authenticated area of the site.

My progress can be seen here: https://github.com/tkiddle/expressPlate/tree/tkiddle

So far I’ve created a way of supporting sub apps and organising controllers per sub app.

The current structure looks a bit like this:

```
ROOT
 | - server.js
 | - package.json
 | - views
    | - index.jade
 | - apps
    | - admin
        | - models
        | - controllers
        | - views
            | - assets
            | - templates (jade templates)
    | - blog 
        | - models
        | - controllers
        | - views
            | - assets
            | - templates (jade templates)
    | - events 
        | - models
        | - controllers
        | - views
            | - assets
            | - templates (jade templates)
```

I’d like to support both isolated views/jade templates (views specific to a specific sub app) and shared view/templates (views that can be shared across multiple sub-apps). My thinking is that when rendering a view within a sub app if the template is not found it looks for it in the ROOT->views directory for it.

This will also allow me to have one common **index.jade** template (in the ROOT->views directory)and for each sub-app’s template/jade files the ability extend that.

I’m at a slight loss with this. Can anyone provide a solution for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the "slight loss" bit of your question but ideally I would recommend putting a `shared` folder in the root folder as well as a `layouts` folder. `shared` can contain shared views like headers, footers etc. while `layouts` can contain application bare-bone pages like application page layout, detail layout etc. If the application needs more clearly separated styles for the sub-apps, you can choose to replicate this structure within the views folder of the sub-app.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This issue isn't about the structural design, it's more about how to intercept express' render functionality.

Before a template is rendered by a sub-app express/middleware should check to see if that template exists in the shared directory.

Answer (score 0):

Note from the future: [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) is the most popular node.js MVC framework nowadays, and has a huge and growing community. It's well-supported and uses the familiar express.js library for routing. Definitely worth looking into for your situation.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue.  For the sub-apps having their own private views directory, you can set the default relative path in jade with app.locals.basedir = 'apps', if you're using express.  So in jade you can just call include /blog/views/templates/blog.jade.  And if you have a shared directory, to be used by all your subapps, you can call include /shared/views/mixins/global-header.jade, for example.

My issue is that I'm trying to do a migrating transition, not all at once.  Therefore, I don't have all my apps in a nice apps or subapps directory, only a few.  I still need to be able to to access the original views directory, which contains the views for every feature, module, app, subapp, mixins, etc...

Using express, it's possible to 'extend' the public directories that will be served to the client using app.use( express.static( '/module1/public' ) and then calling it again for another directory, app.use( express.static( '/module2/public' ).  I wish there were a way to *extend* the views directory in a similar fashion.  Is there?  Is it possible to assemble a collection of views?  Using this file structure, for example, it would be nice to have an app.basedir.use( 'blog/views' ) and call again to extend, app.basedir.use( 'events/views' ), and then in Jade I'd only have to call, include blog-base.jade and event-base.jade even though they technically reside in different views directories.